# How do I output a stream of tuples from a Storm spout with emit() and sync()?

Tags: node.js, apache-storm, hortonworks-data-platform

([xpost github issue](https://github.com/RallySoftware/node-storm/issues/5))

I'm new to Storm. I found the helpful node-storm library and I have successfully submitted topologies, but I can't get my spout to emit a stream of tuples.

node-storm's `wordcount` example works fine.

I want a spout that subscribes to a websocket and outputs any messages as tuples.

Here's my attempt so far. I think I have some misconfiguration, because I know I my `wsEmitter` is emitting `future` events, but my Storm UI shows zero spout emits.

I suspect that maybe I shouldn't be binding the listener inside the spout function?

Does this function get invoked multiple times? (looks like it... see https://github.com/RallySoftware/node-storm/blob/master/lib/spout.js#L4 )

What does `sync` actually do and when should I use it?

```
var storm = require('node-storm');
var wsEmitter = require('./wsEmitter.js')();
wsEmitter.init();  // subscribe to websocket

var futuresSpout = storm.spout(function(sync) {
  var self = this;
  console.log('subscribing to ws');
  wsEmitter.on('future', function(data){       // websocket data arrived
    self.emit([data]);
    sync();
  });
})
.declareOutputFields(["a"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had two problems. First, my topology wasn't executing because one of my bolts (not shown) failed to set `.declareOutputFields()`.

Second, I need to delay the emits from the spout until the supervisor asks for one emit with `nextTick()`. I did that by buffering any incoming messages until the supervisor calls the spout:

```
module.exports = (function(){
  var storm = require('node-storm');

  var wsEmitter = require('./wsEmitter.js')();
  wsEmitter.init();

  var queue = [];
  var queueEmpty = true;

  wsEmitter.on('thing', function(data){
    var trade = JSON.parse(data);
    trade.timeReported = new Date().valueOf();
    queue.push(trade);
    queueEmpty = false;
  });

  return storm.spout(function(sync) {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(!queueEmpty){
        self.emit([queue.shift()]);
        queueEmpty =
        ( queue.length === 0
        ? true
        : false )
      }
      sync();
    }, 100);

  })
  .declareOutputFields(['trade'])
})()
```